# What does p stand for in "fp" of with open(filename, "w") as fp:

Tags: python

It might be extremely frivolous, but google searches are not helpful indeed.

In python official docs, it constantly refers file as fp:

```
with open(filename, "w") as fp:
fp.write()
```

What's does "p" stand for?

Comment: sometimes people (especially linux users) use `fd` instead meaning "file descriptor".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"fp" stands for "file pointer" and it was a pointer to a `FILE` structure in C. The name "fp" just sort of stuck.

"fd" was an alternate and usually indicated an unsigned integer, which was the offset of the referenced file in the "file table" (file *descriptor*).

Answer (score 5):

1. It's an entirely arbitrary name, but I think you understand that.
2. It's usually **f**ile **p**ointer.